# scala extends java generic array failure

Tags: java, arrays, scala

1. I have a Java interface with generic param.

```
public interface JavaInterface<T> {
  void sayHi(T[] keys);
}
```

2. I can implement a Java class like

```
public class JavaInterfaceImpl implements JavaInterface<String> {
  @Override
  public void sayHi(String[] array) {
  }
}
```

3. However, when creating a Scala class to implement the interface, it failed

```
class ScalaInterfaceImpl extends JavaInterface[String] {
   override def sayHi(keys: Array[String]): Unit = {}
}
```

Here are the error messages.

```
class ScalaInterfaceImpl needs to be abstract, since method sayHi in trait JavaInterface of type (x$1: Array[String])Unit is not defined
(Note that Array[T with Object] does not match Array[String]: their type parameters differ)
class ScalaInterfaceImpl extends JavaInterface[String] {
```

and

```
method sayHi overrides nothing.
Note: the super classes of class ScalaInterfaceImpl contain the following, non final members named sayHi:
def sayHi(x$1: Array[String]): Unit
   override def sayHi(keys: Array[String]): Unit = {}
```

4. However, if I'm implementing the Scala class for this `trait`, things goes fine.

```
trait ScalaInterface[T] {
  def sayHi(keys: Array[T]): Unit
}
```

5. The Java interface in `1` is not changeable (from a third-party lib), hence I'm blocked in `3`.

update 1. I find it works with the following code

```
class ScalaInterfaceImpl extends JavaInterface[String] {
  override def sayHi(keys: Array[String with Object]): Unit = {}
}
```

Can anyone help explain it?

Comment: I am not totally sure but probably something about type erasure. Maybe, you can first extend the **Java** `interface` using a **Scala** `trait` that does the weird interop bits so all **Scala** implementations are simpler? In any case you should want to avoid `Array` in **Scala** code thus it sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Generic arrays are represented slightly different between the two languages. Even though they are not type erased, their enclosing generic trait and interface have their type parameter `T` erased at compile-time.

First, consider the Scala example:

```
trait ScalaInterface[T] {
  def sayHi(keys: Array[T]): Unit
}
```

After `scalac` compiles it, this becomes:

```
public interface ScalaInterface {
  void sayHi(Object var1);
}
```

Whereas the Java interface:

```
public interface JavaInterface<T> {
  void sayHi(T[] keys);
}
```

After `javac` compiles it, this becomes:

```
public interface JavaInterface {
  void sayHi(Object[] var1);
}
```

The slightly different signature between the two looks harmless at first, but it actually makes the difference. Why Scala represents them differently is explained [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/arrays.html):

> What about *genericity*? In Java, you cannot write a `T[]` where `T` is a
> type parameter. How then is Scala’s `Array[T]` represented? In fact a
> generic array like `Array[T]` could be at run-time any of Java’s eight
> primitive array types `byte[]`, `short[]`, `char[]`, `int[]`, `long[]`, `float[]`,
> `double[]`, `boolean[]`, or it could be an array of objects. The only
> common run-time type encompassing all of these types is `AnyRef` (or,
> equivalently `java.lang.Object`), so that’s the type to which the Scala
> compiler maps `Array[T]`.

When you used `JavaInterface<T>`, you actually placed the type `Object` as the upper bound of type `T`, at every location where `T` is used in the interface, in this case in the `sayHi` method. This happens because of type erasure.

On the other hand, the type `T` in the generic trait `ScalaInterface[T]` is not bounded to `Object`; it's bounded to `Any` because that's the base type in Scala. This means `T` has different upper bounds between the two languages in the method `sayHi`.

Therefore, even though  `JavaInterface<T>` and `ScalaInterface[T]` look similar, their `sayHi` method is not really equivalent. The `scalac` compiler does some type inference under the hood, checks the location where type `T` is used and concludes that the `sayHi` method needs the following type constraint:

```
trait ScalaInterface[T] {
  def sayHi(keys: Array[T with Object]): Unit
}
```

This is actually how your `JavaInterface` is treated and why using `String with Object` fixes the issue.

A question that arises is why Scala does not instead use `Object` as the upper bound of the generic type:

```
trait ScalaInterface[T <: Object] {
  def sayHi(keys: Array[T]): Unit
}
```

While this works for this particular use case, it's too constraining, because you would never be able to use subtypes of `AnyVal` in type `T` at all, so `ScalaInterface[Int]` or `ScalaInterface[Double]` would be impossible, just because the interface has a method that takes a generic array as argument.

If your interface did not have a method taking a generic array as argument it would not need this constrain at all. Or if your interface had another method that took a simple argument of type `T`, that would constrained as well. Such considerations show the issue is not actually in the type argument `T`, but in the method `sayHi`, so this is where the issue is pinpointed and contained.